# Logstash records from a server being rejected by ElasticSearch due to malformed date

Tags: logstash, log4j2, logstash-grok

I am in the process of installing ELK including REDIS and have successfully got one server/process delivering its logs through to ElasticSearch(ES).
Most happy with this.
However, on updating an existing server/process to start using logstash I am seeing the logdate come through in the form yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,sss.
Note the absence of the **T** between date and time. ES is not happy with this.

Log4j pattern in use by both servers is:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="~%d{ISO8601} [%p] [%t] [%c{1.}] %m%n"/>
```

Logstash config is identical with the exception of the path to the source log file

```
input{

    file{
        type => "log4j"
        path => "/var/log/restapi/*.log"
        add_field => {
            "process" => "restapi"
            "environment" => "DEVELOPMENT"
        }
        codec => multiline {

           pattern => "^~%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
           negate => "true"
           what => "previous"
        }
    }


}

filter{

    if [type] == "log4j"{
        grok{
            match => {
                message => "~%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}%{SPACE}\[%{LOGLEVEL:level}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:thread}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:category}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:messagetext}"
            }            
        }


    }

}

output{
    redis{
        host => "sched01"
        data_type => "list"
        key => "logstash"
        codec => json
    }

    stdout{codec => rubydebug}

}
```

The stdout line is for current debug purposes, whereby it is evident that on correctly working server that logdate is being correctly formed by the GROK filter.
[image: Good Log Date format]

compared to the incorrectly formed output.
[image: Bad log date format]

The only difference from a high level is when the servers were built.
Looking for ideas on what could be causing or a means to add the T into the field

Comment: Then I see that the source date value is coming through without the **T** in the log file, which makes this now more of a log4j issue. Why is a similar log4j pattern producing a different output.

Comment: And that was that. Found that the older service was using a beta release of log4j2 after finding that a bug had been identified and fixed within log4j2. A POM update and build later and am seeing the data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug raised under **DatePatternConverter ISO8601_PATTERN does not conform to ISO8601** https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-670 led me to check the version of the log4j2 library used in the older application. Found it was Beta. Updated to v2.3 and the dateTime value started to populate correctly. The value now being correctly formed, ElasticSearch is happy to accept it.